# Apply Stylesheet From Frontend Skin Folder To Admin Page Via A Layout Handle

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, adminhtml, layout

I am looking to apply a stylesheet located in the skin/frontend/default/mytheme/css folder to a page inside the admin area of Magento. See the layout XML I am using to add this stylesheet to the admin page below:

```
<my_custom_admin_layout_handle>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                 <type>skin_css</type>
                 <file>css/my-custom-stylesheet.css</file>
            </action>
        </reference>
</my_custom_admin_layout_handle>
```

The code does add the stylesheet link tag to the page but references the href as skin/adminhtml/base/default/css/my-custom-stylesheet.css. See link tag added to page below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/skin/adminhtml/base/default/css/personalshop.css" media="all" />
```

Is there a way that I can get the stylesheet href to reference the stylesheet in the folder skin/frontend/default/mytheme/css using the layout handle above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need put the css  admin area.

Admin css located at  `skin/adminhtml/<AdminPackage>/<Admintemplate>`.

`my-custom-stylesheet.css`  should located at `skin/adminhtml/default/default/css`

code is right:

```
<my_custom_admin_layout_handle>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                 <type>skin_css</type>
                 <file>css/my-custom-stylesheet.css</file>
            </action>
        </reference>
</my_custom_admin_layout_handle>
```

Comment: Hi Amit, This would mean duplicating code though and the styles contained inside the file will be shared on both frontend and admin pages. I want this to remain the same without the need to update the code in 2 places if there are updates to the stylesheet in the future.

Comment: according my concept .it too complex

Comment: thanks for your response. Are you saying that it can't be done?

Comment: possible.but it loo complex to do this type.. wasted of time.. I totally my  thought